# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte' to type 'System.Byte[]' - vb .net

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, byte

So I have a Function that is supposed to convert an image to a `byte()` and then return a `string`. However, I am having some issues with this.
Here is the function:

```
Shared Function saveSknI(ByVal tosave As Image) As String
    Dim converter As New ImageConverter
    Dim returnValue As String = ""
    For Each imageByte As Byte() In converter.ConvertTo(tosave, GetType(Byte()))
        returnValue = returnValue & Convert.ToBase64String(imageByte)
    Next
    Return returnValue
End Function
```

This Function returns an a `System.InvalidCastException` exception.
It looks like this:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in ***.exe
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte' to type 'System.Byte[]'.

I am using vb .net and I don't get why this isn't working, I've scanned the entire project for just `byte` not `byte()` and it didn't come up with anything.

Comment: Your function returns a String.

Comment: I made a mistake writing the first sentence, I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is declared as string:

```
Shared Function saveSknI(ByVal tosave As Image) As String
```

So it cant/wont return a byte array.  Also, the image converter doesnt convert byte by byte.  This line wont compile for me (using Option Strict):

```
For Each imageByte As Byte() In converter.ConvertTo(tosave, GetType(Byte()))
```

At a minimum, I think you meant `For Each imageByte As Byte` since there is only one array.  Also, `ConvertTo` returns `Object` which you have not converted but are trying to iterate.  You dont need to convert to Base64 byte by byte either.  Corrected and collapsed:

```
Shared Function saveSknI(tosave As Image) As String
    Dim converter As New ImageConverter

    Dim bytes = DirectCast(converter.ConvertTo(tosave, GetType(Byte())), Byte())
    Return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)
End Function
```

---

This does almost the same exact thing as `ImageConverter` without the boxing:

```
Public Function ToByteArray(img As Image, imgFormat As ImageFormat) As Byte()
    Dim tmpData As Byte()
    Using ms As New MemoryStream()
        img.Save(ms, imgFormat)
        tmpData = ms.ToArray
    End Using
    Return tmpData
End Function
```

Slap `<Extension()>` on it and place it in a module and you can use it as an extenstion:

```
imgBytes = myImg.ToByteArray(ImageFormat.PNG)
```

To convert the result to Base64:

```
imgB64 = Convert.ToBase64String(imgBytes)
```

If you so desired, you could create a `ToBase64String()` extension and do the conversion there in one step.

Comment: How would you convert a byte into an image? Would it be similar?

Comment: Its basically the reverse.  But, if you are starting with a B64 string, convert to byte() then create an image from a memstream created from the array.  That can be written as an extension too: `Dim img = myBytes.ToImage()`